# Alcohol-fuel for burner in Spain

Tags: food-and-drink, spain, backpacking, malaga

We travel to malaga next weekend and from there on we will hike in the sierra nevada. I was there a few years ago and remember that we have had big trouble to find any Aclcohol-fuel for our burner.

1. What is the name for this in spanish?
2. Where can I find it?
3. Are there any outdoor shops in Malaga?

Comment: What is Alcohol fuel? Simply ethanol? This ethanol gel?

Comment: Simply ethanol would be perfect for my stove.

Comment: How much do you need? http://manuelriesgo.com/index.php?id_product=459&controller=product&search_query=etanol&results=4 this is five litres. Sorry I do not know an offline shop.

Comment: I need about half a liter. In some countries you get it in the pharmacy but I am not sure if that is the case in Spain. I will arrive at malaga airport at 9:40 and have to take the bus to motril at 11:15. So, either I have to get some there or I have to get some in Lanjaron. But the chance to get ethanol there is (i reckon) close to zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How big is your burner? Take your burner to a local ferreteria (hardware store), and simply say 'Tienes Combustible de alcohol' . That should do the trick. If not go to the big department store EL CORTE INGLES (you will find them online). They have a huge camping/outdoor department and should know where to get it if they don't stock it. Have a great time in Spain!

Here's the link for El Corte Ingles

https://www.elcorteingles.es/centroscomerciales/es/eci/centros/centro-comercial-malaga

Comment: [Combustible para biochimenea](http://www.elcorteingles.es/hogar/A18538099-combustible-para-biochimenea-climacity/) on the Corte Inglés website. It's actually in the *Terraza y Jardín* (verandah and garden) department.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Taylor .  That makes more sense to me, I knew I had seen it in an El Corte Inglese, I just had the wrong department.  Hopefully the OP can find it when he gets there.